# MySQL Query lowest value within range not in table

Tags: mysql

So, I have a table with some unique numbers.

Let's say the range is 1 to 1000.

I want to do a select query that gets the lowest free number within a given range.

So, for example: `where number > 10 and number < 200`. If there are no numbers within this range I would like to return `10`.

If there happens to be the numbers `11,12,13, 15, 16` within this range. I'd like to return `14`.

I was trying something like below but to no avail.

```
SELECT MIN(number)
FROM 
(SELECT 10 number  
UNION 
SELECT number+1 FROM table) a
WHERE number < 200 AND number 
NOT IN (SELECT number FROM table);
```

Thanks.

Comment: If there happens to be the numbers 11,12,13, 15, 16 within this range. I'd like to return 14.
 what do you mean by this, is 14 the lowest value number here ?

Comment: @Mubo yes 14 will be the lowest number. If the query was based on where number > 10 and number < 200. Thanks

Comment: @Mubo: OP wants to fetch least of the missing numbers within a given  range of numbers.

Comment: I don't understand the criterion for returning 14 as opposed to 10 (or 17). 10 is the lowest available number in the range !?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(MIN(t1.n) + 1, 10)
  FROM (SELECT n
          FROM t
         WHERE n > 10   # lower bound, exclusive
           AND n < 199  # upper bound, inclusive
     UNION ALL
        SELECT 10) t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2
    ON t2.n = t1.n + 1
 WHERE t2.n IS NULL;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e2e8c/1/0)

Comment: If the range starts with numbers that are not already in the table then this won't find them. For example if the range was > 10 to < 200 and the table contained 12, 13 and 15 it will return 14 and not 11.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a range of numbers (in this case 1 to 1000) and LEFT JOINing that against your table and finding the non matches. Using MIN to get the smallest number from the generated range that wasn't found on the table.

```
SELECT MIN(iNum)
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 AS iNum
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)tens
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)hundreds
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table b
ON a.iNum = b.number
WHERE a.iNum BETWEEN 10 AND 200
AND b.number IS NULL
```